# Magento2: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2, template, fatal-error

Got the error below:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Config\DataInterface in /var/www/html/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73
( ! ) Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Config\DataInterface in /var/www/html/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue is in the custom plugin located in:
**Magebees\Layerednavigation\Model\Plugin\Page.php** in function aroundRenderResult(...)

To make sure that it's about that, I suggest to temporarily disable this plugin / full extension and check whether the issue will still be there. If not, you'll need to debug the code of the function to see why this happens.

Comment: Ok, I will check.