# Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2.3.3, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.3.14. I was in my root directory and entered the command `bin/magento setup:install` and got this error. What is going on?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Project\Crawler\Api\CrawlerItemRepositoryInterface in /var/www/html/root/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/root/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Project\\Crawler...')
    #1 /var/www/html/root/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Project\\Crawler...')
    #2 /var/www/html/root/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Project\\Crawler...', NULL, 'crawlerItemRepo...', 'Project\\ImageCr...')
    #3 /var/www/html/root/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Project\\ImageCr...', Array, A in /var/www/html/root/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

I have been looking at these but they didn't work for me:

- [Magento2: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246300/magento2-fatal-error-uncaught-error-cannot-instantiate-interface)
- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/upgrade-to-2-3-2-error-developer-php/td-p/136666
- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/upgrade-to-2-3-2-error-developer-php/td-p/136666
- [Cannot instantiate interface Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Layer\\FilterableAttributeListInterface](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151110/cannot-instantiate-interface-magento-catalog-model-layer-filterableattribute?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento in attempting to instantiate the interface, interfaces cannot be instantiated. You need a class that implements the interface.

To do this use a preference in the di.xml that suggests which class to use for the CrawlerItemRepositoryInterface

Comment: Ow yea you are right. Nvm my answer

Answer (score 1):

Well it does not find that interface or can not load it and that can have multiple reasons.

Here a couple :

1. Your interface does not exist
2. The interface has the wrong namespace
3. The interface is in the wrong directory structure
4. The interface wrong syntaxes
5. The interface is opened with a `<?` tag instead of a `<?php` tag and your php settings does not allow shorthand php opening tags

**EDIT**

See Netstorm's answer. Will leave this here for debugging purposes for other people

Answer (score 0):

**ADDITIONALLY to a correct di.xml**

In Magento 2.4.5-p1.
I found that dependency between files with the SAME $this->variable name CAN cause this issue.

**Solution: Change the variable name from**

```
$this->mymodelFactory = $mymodelFactory;
```

To

```
$this->_mymodelFactory = $_mymodelFactory;
```

.
.
.
**Then:**
**Error > Cannot instantiate interface**

*Vendor/Module/Model/Order.php*

```
protected MymodelFactory $mymodelFactory;

_ _construct(
... 
MymodelRepositoryInterface $mymodelRepository,
MymodelFactory $mymodelFactory
){
$this->mymodelRepository = $mymodelRepository;
$this->mymodelFactory = $mymodelFactory;
}
```

*di.xml*

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\MymodelRepositoryInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\MymodelRepository"/>
```

*Vendor/Module/Model/MymodelRepository.php*

```
_ _construct(
... 
MymodelFactory $mymodelFactory
){
$this->mymodelFactory = $mymodelFactory
}
```

.
.
.
**NOW:**
**No errors**

*Vendor/Module/Model/Order.php*

```
protected MymodelFactory $_mymodelFactory;

_ _construct(
... 
MymodelRepositoryInterface $mymodelRepository,
MymodelFactory $_mymodelFactory
){
$this->mymodelRepository = $mymodelRepository;
$this->_mymodelFactory = $_mymodelFactory;
}
```

*di.xml*

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\MymodelRepositoryInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\MymodelRepository"/>
```

*Vendor/Module/Model/MymodelRepository.php*

```
_ _construct(
... 
MymodelFactory $mymodelFactory
){
$this->mymodelFactory = $mymodelFactory
}
```